# How to keep triggering a method while the button is pressed on React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm implementing an input number using React. This input number has a + and - button that increases or decreases the value inside an input.
[image]

The `onClick` methods works fine, however, I wonder, what's the method to keep triggering the `increase` or `decrease` methods while the button keeps pressed.

Here are my methods to update the state:

```
  const increaseValue = () => {
    const val = isNaN(tempValue) || tempValue === '' ? 0 : Number(tempValue)
    setTempValue(val + 1)
  }

  const decreaseValue = () => {
    const val = isNaN(tempValue) || tempValue === '' ? 0 : Number(tempValue)
    setTempValue(val - 1)
  }
```

and here's the component

```
    <div className="flex flex-row h-8 w-20 rounded-lg relative bg-transparent">
      <button
        className=" bg-action text-action-100 hover:text-gray-300 hover:bg-action-300 h-full w-20 rounded-l cursor-pointer outline-none active:bg-action-200"
        onClick={decreaseValue}
      >
        <span className="m-auto text-md font-thin">−</span>
      </button>
      <input
        className="outline-none focus:outline-none text-center w-full bg-action font-thin text-xs antialiased flex items-center text-white"
        name="custom-input-number"
        value={tempValue}
        onChange={e => {
          setTempValue(e.target.value)
          type === 'number' && setIsEditing(true)
        }}
      ></input>
      <button
        className="bg-action text-action-100 hover:text-gray-300 hover:bg-action-300 h-full w-20 rounded-r cursor-pointer active:bg-action-200"
        onClick={increaseValue}
      >
        <span className="m-auto text-md font-thin">+</span>
      </button>
    </div>
```

Now, I want to add the feature to keep increasing/decreasing while the button is still pressed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click and Hold event listener with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573922/click-and-hold-event-listener-with-javascript)

Comment: I'm not sure whether using setInterval is right because it's currently throwing an exception: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.(while the component is mounted and visible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is probably to keep track of when a button is first pressed and then when it is released, and using a `useRef` to keep track of a time interval for how often the button action should trigger. That will look like this:

```
const intervalRef = useRef(null);
```

Then we need a function to handle when we begin pressing the plus button:

```
  const startCountUp = () => {
    if (intervalRef.current) return;
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTempValue((prevCounter) => prevCounter + 1);
    }, 10);
  };
```

We'll add a similar function for when the user presses the minus button, which counts down:

```
  const startCountDown = () => {
    if (intervalRef.current) return;
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTempValue((prevCounter) => prevCounter - 1);
    }, 10);
  };
```

Next, we need a way to stop incrementing the counter when we release the button. We'll create a function to handle stopping the timer:

```
  const stopCounter = () => {
    if (intervalRef.current) {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
      intervalRef.current = null;
    }
  };
```

Then we need to trigger our functions properly when the user interacts with a button. Our button's `onMouseDown` should call `startCountUp` (for the + button), and when the user releases the mouse we want to use `onMouseUp` to call `stopCounter` so we stop incrementing the counter. Also, we want to be prepared for the case where the user moves their mouse outside of the button, so we use `onMouseLeave` to also call `stopCounter`.

All put together, here's what that looks like:

```
  const [tempValue, setTempValue] = useState(0);
  const intervalRef = useRef(null);

  const startCountUp = () => {
    if (intervalRef.current) return;
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTempValue((prevCounter) => prevCounter + 1);
    }, 10);
  };

  const startCountDown = () => {
    if (intervalRef.current) return;
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(() => {
      setTempValue((prevCounter) => prevCounter - 1);
    }, 10);
  };

  const stopCounter = () => {
    if (intervalRef.current) {
      clearInterval(intervalRef.current);
      intervalRef.current = null;
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => stopCounter(); // when App is unmounted we should stop counter
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button
          onMouseDown={startCountDown}
          onMouseUp={stopCounter}
          onMouseLeave={stopCounter}
        >
          <span>−</span>
        </button>
        <input
          name="custom-input-number"
          value={tempValue}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setTempValue(e.target.value);
          }}
        ></input>
        <button
          onMouseDown={startCountUp}
          onMouseUp={stopCounter}
          onMouseLeave={stopCounter}
        >
          <span>+</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

And here's a full example of that on CodeSandbox: [image: Edit React Click and Hold Button]